# Printing source code with OS X

Tags: macos, printing

How can I print source code in OS X (HTML/PHP) with number lines and without long line truncation? I was used to Gedit on Linux, but here it seems I can't obtain the same with applications such as TextWrangler or TextEdit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can print source code with line numbers and without truncation in [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/TextWrangler/), the key is **Soft wrap text**.

1. Turn on "Soft Wrap Text" under Text Options.
2. Open TextWrangler > Preferences
3. Select "Text Printing" then check the "Print line numbers" checkbox.
4. Print again, long lines should wrap and line numbers should be present.

*Note: you may want to set up "Editor Defaults" in TextWrangler's Preferences, and have it Soft wrap text for you for each file you edit, and to a specified width too.*

Answer (score 4):

`enscript` can be installed via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) and used via Terminal. Start with

```
enscript -CG2rE -U2 my-source-file.PHP
```

and read the (extensive) man page for additional features.

Comment: Presumably you need to find and install this, because it's not in my path on OS X.

Comment: @OliverBock Indeed. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at GeSHi? http://qbnz.com/highlighter/demo.php

You didn't specify the purpose for printing out - but I use this to "prettify" any code I expect to be printed - it does line numbering and syntax highlighting for a wide range of languages.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

**TextWranger** is the best on Mac OS when it come to printing out source code.

**Step 1**

[image]

**Step 2**

[image]

**Step 3**

Then, there is one more settings, click on gear icon on the top left

[image]

---

**Amazing Result**

*Color, Line numbers, just neat and clean ...*

Here is a screen of my PDF to show to you guys

[image]

Enjoy !!!

Answer (score 1):

for Catalina, you must use BBedit (textWrangler is not compatible with Catalina)
so:

[image]